# Wie ist es richtig? "Die Kleinen hängt/henkt man und die Großen läßt man laufen"

Tags: word-choice, proverb

Wie ist der Spruch denn nun richtig? Mit dem Verb `henken` oder dem Verb `hängen`?

Da [henken](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH06215#XGH06215) und hängen verwandt sind und sich auch die Bedeutung des Spruchs allenfalls in Nuancen ändert, habe ich mich gefragt welche Version des Spruches denn nun die richtige ist, oder ob gar beide nebeneinander existieren.

Die Aussprache unterscheidet sich auch - vermutlich je nach Sprachregion - nur unwesentlich voneinander (aufgrund des kt, bzw. gt).

Ginge man nach den üblichen Suchmaschinen, wäre die Variante mit `hängen` die einzig gültige.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Der Spruch verwendet »hängen«:

> [Die Kleinen hängt man, die Großen lässt man laufen](https://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=h%C3%A4ngt%20man&bool=relevanz&gawoe=an&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_ou&suchspalte%5B%5D=rart_varianten_ou)

Was die Wörterbücher sagen, kann ich nur bestätigen, mit »henken« ist mir die Wendung noch nicht untergekommen.

Comment: Ich kenne das auch so, würde an eine Version mit *henkt* aber auch nicht "falsch" dranschreiben.

Answer (score 3):

Meines Erachtens sind beide Varianten in Ordnung. Ich persönlich tendiere eher zu henken, da das Wort genau dafür geschaffen wurde. Allerdings scheint sich das Wort als Verb im Sprachgebrauch nicht durchgesetzt zu haben. Aufhängen wäre wohl das richtigere Equivalent zu henken, aber man spart sich auch noch das "auf".

Eine eindeutige Regel für die korrekte Verwendung, außer vlt. der Häufigkeit als Richtlinie, gibt es nicht. Wiktionary schreibt zu [henken](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/henken), daß es veraltend wäre. Von daher würde man sich wahrscheinlich wundern, wenn henken tatsächlich benutzt würde. Es wäre aber nicht falsch.

Comment: Das Grimm'sche Wörterbuch erläutert, dass "henken" hauptsächlich im oberdeutschen Sprachraum verwendet wurde, weniger im mitteldeutschen. Und ebendort wird das Sprichwort auch nur in der Form mit "hängen" erwähnt.

Answer (score 1):

Ich kenn's auch nur mit '*hängen*'. Es gibt ein ähnliches Sprichwort:

> Mitgefangen - mitgehangen.

[Laut dict.cc auf Englisch 'Cling together, swing together!']

In früheren Zeiten gab's noch keine 'Sozialstunden', da war man wie es scheint nicht sehr zimperlich.

Man könnte einwenden, dass hier der Reim maßgeblich ist. Es scheint so zu sein, dass in der Tat bei Redensarten wie '*Mitgefangen - mitgehangen*' zumindest gelegentlich auch '**henken**' in Gebrauch war. Redensarten-index.de verweist auf Georg Tobias Pistorius: Teutsch-juristischer Sprichwörterschatz, 1716 - 1725. Dort findet man auf Seite 116 (= Bildschirmseite 141 der PDF-Ausgabe)

> "Mitgestohlen, **mitgehencket**; (...)
>
> Mitgehuret, miterträncket"

sowie

> "Den dieb soll man **hencken**
>
> und die hur erträncken"

und schließlich

> "Mit gemachet, mit gesündiget,
>
> Mit begangen, mit gefangen,
>
> Mit gestohlen, mit **gehangen**."

Hier sieht man sehr schön, dass der Reim sehr wohl eine Rolle spielt.